# SQL FullText search with different combinations of empty inputs, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search, parameters, full-text-search

Say my SQL table has columns `Title`, `Price`, `YearsOld` and I want to search for matching results using input forms from an html page.

I want the user to be able to leave whatever input forms blank that they wish. So if they left all fields blank, it would return every entry. If they left `Title` blank but entered a `maxPrice` and `maxAge` then it would show all the items with prices and ages lower than the `maxPrice` and `maxAge` that they submit, regardless of title.

Do I have to account for every single combination of blank / not blank field entries with if statements? Or is there a better way to do this?

For example, I want to avoid code that would look anything like this:

```
 if($_POST['titleSearch' == "") {
    if($_POST['maxAge'] == NULL) {
        if($_POST['maxPrice'] == NULL) {
            $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
    }
    else if($_POST['maxAge'] != NULL) {
        if($_POST['maxPrice'] == NULL) {
            $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table 
                WHERE age <  $_POST['maxAge'])";
        }

      # etc etc etc

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: ***Never*** store a calculated field (`YearsOld`)

Comment: Calculated? In this scenario YearsOld would just be a value that was entered into the table at some point, not really calculated from anything. Just an example variable name.

Answer (score 0):

a more efficient way is:

```
$tSet = strlen($_POST['titleSearch']);
$aSet = strlen($_POST['maxAge']);

if(!$tSet && !$aSet){
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
} else if ($tSet && !$aSet){
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title=" . $_POST['titleSearch']);
}
```